# Should i use redux for controlling React Native App Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Currently i have made a MVP application for Android with **React Native**. The App has the next parts:

- A sidenav with 4 options: *Make a review, add a new vehicle, look the day reviews, and configuration*.
- A login screen.
- A process of review which basically is a serie of screens: *Search for a car, update the car data, choose a review type, take some photos and finally do the review in the last screen.*

Right now i am only using redux in the Login Screen but the review flow seems to be wrong, because after every step i just do something like:

`this.props.navigator.push({ nextScreen... });`

And my question are:

Should i use Redux for controlling the flow between screens?

Some advice for do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should imo) if u are using NavigatorExperimental. It plays nicely with redux. With the Navigator it could be a little bit different. You can find sample implementation for NavigatorExperimental here:  https://medium.com/@satya164/react-natives-navigationexperimental-with-redux-467acee02756#.few6s5ksz